# iframe name attribute with angular expression

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I have an iframe whose name is taken from a scope variable.

```
<iframe width="100%" name="{{frameName}}" ng-src="{{frameUrl}}"></iframe>
```

my problem is that the frame is "registered" in the window.frames object as

```
window.frames["{{frameName}}"]
```

I noticed that with jquery I am able to retrieve the iframe by it's name after the expression was evaluated but I do not want to include jQuery only for this purpose.

This might be too much of an edge case but I am thinking angular should re-register this iframe with the real name after the expression was evaluated.

Is ther a different solution beside including jquery to my app?

Comment: What if you try with `ng-attr-name` instead of `name`?

Comment: have you considered a directive that sets name from another attribute? Or can even just clean up the expression value in window.frames from directive

Comment: @Blackhole that didn't do the trick either. I had to hard code the frame name.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Ep6EK/) and check your console.

Comment: this is very interesting the console prints out "undefined" for me. I am using chrome 31.0.1650.57 (the most updated version)

Comment: I only get this problem when using the one-time binding "::" operator.